# Make a link active in HAML with current_page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

So i got this bad code (the link disappears when it's not the root path.):

```
    = link_to "News", root_path, class: "active" if current_page?(root_path)
```

I would like to make the link's class .active when the current_page is root_path.

Trying to find the Rails Way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

enclose the option for `class` in a parenthesis

```
= link_to "News", root_path, class: ("active" if current_page?(root_path))
```